# How to force DecisionTreeRegressor to use polyfit equation instead of mse at leaf level in python SKlearn

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I am using python SKlearn DecisionTreeRegressor for my data. As DecisionTreeRegressor defines constant data at leaf node, my prediction is looking like a step, instead I wanted to force polyfit Equation of my interest. I was looking some thing like to use Decision tree to some depth, then apply normal regression at leaf node to predict continuous data.
For my data set normal regression doesn't work as it looks for global error minimization, so i am looking for this.
I am a beginner, any response would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are decision trees with linear regression in the leafs. See [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78563/regression-tree-algorithm-with-linear-regression-models-in-each-leaf). But they are very slow to build, and do not come with sklearn. Have you tried a decision tree ensemble like [`Random Forest`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)? If you use `n_estimators=1000` or bigger, you should not notice any step behavior. Random forests and gradient boosting trees generally win most data mining competitions.

Answer (score 2):

This is an expanded answer based on my comment.

First of all, there are many interesting **highly non-linear classifiers** besides decision trees. Most widely used are [neural networks](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) and [SVMs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html). (Nitpick but SVMs can be seen as neural networks.)

Within the **world of decision trees,** there are things like decision trees that have linear regressions [in the nodes.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78563/regression-tree-algorithm-with-linear-regression-models-in-each-leaf) However, these are very slow to train. The problem is that you can no longer take advantage of the fact that decision trees entropy or gini score can be calculated incrementally as the threshold $t$ is varied (where $t$ is the right-hand part of the node rule, $x_i < t$). This trick can not be used for these trees. There are of course many other rule induction algorithms besides decision trees, which are not as step-like.

Anyhow, **usually ensembles are used.** Ensembles are models made of several models, which then "vote" on the result. You can use them with any class of models, but they are particularly excellent when combined with decision trees because:

1. Decision trees can have very different results if the sample is slightly different. Ensembles fix that;
2. Decision trees decision boundaries are orthogonal to the features, which have "step" effects;
3. Decision trees have to be pruned, while some ensembles can be used without pruning;
4. Most winners of Kaggle and other data mining competitions have used decision trees ensembles;
5. Ensembles give you probabilities if you need them; probabilities from decision trees are highly dependent on how you prune them (and unpruned decision trees cannot give you probabilities at all).

[See here the results](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_iris.html) of some decision trees ensembles:

[image: decision trees ensembles]

There are two types of ensembles widely used:

1. [Random Forest:](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) where each decision tree is trained independently.
2. [Gradient Boosting Trees:](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) these are based on AdaBoost. The idea is that the next tree is trained by weighting more strongly the observations that the previous trees have not been able to qualify correctly.

Usually, Kaggle winners use gradient boosting trees, especially using the [xgboost package.](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) But they have more hyperparameters to tweak, so if you don't have much time to tweak them, just go with a random forest. Gradient boosting trees are more ticky to get right, and the results can be different if you change parameters like `n_estimators`. Random forests, on the other hand, tend to the expected behavior when `n_estimators`$\rightarrow\infty$.

Also, gradient boosting trees can overfit, albeit I think it's rare. (Random forests can also overfit, but it is because the underlying estimator is overfitting. They tend to the average behavior as you increase `n_estimators`. Tell me if this isn't clear.)

*Note:* `n_estimators` in sklearn is sometimes very low, and you should increment it. In real problems, people use thousands of trees.